# how to pass jquery value to my controller using Request.Form method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I Want to pass factor id to the controller using Request.Form Method , I try to pass it in the name attribute but it does not work

This is my Jquery function:

```
 $("#categoryId").change(function () {
$.get("/Organization/GetFactorsList", { Id: $("#categoryId").val() }, function (data) {
            $("#factors").empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                $("#factors").append("<div class='row factors'><div 
    class='col-md-3'><div class='checkbox'><label><input type='checkbox' 
 id='blankCheckbox' value='option1' name='" + row.id + "'/></label></div> 
 </div><div class='col-md-9 factor'>" + row.Name + "</div></div>")

            });

        });
    })
```

Comment: show your controller code as well

Answer (score 0):

try this solution :

```
$("#categoryId").change(function () {
$.get("/Organization/GetFactorsList",data : { Id: $("#categoryId").val() }, function (data) {
            $("#factors").empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                $("#factors").append("<div class='row factors'><div 
    class='col-md-3'><div class='checkbox'><label><input type='checkbox' 
 id='blankCheckbox' value='option1' name='" + row.id + "'/></label></div> 
 </div><div class='col-md-9 factor'>" + row.Name + "</div></div>")

            });

        });
    })
```

you're forget to add data : { Id: $("#categoryId").val() }